# Convert date retrieved from Stack Exchange API to some readable format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp, stackexchange-api

I retrieved data from the Stack Exchange API as json data and the data column was like below.

```
"last_activity_date": 1587151634,
"creation_date": 1584079887,
"last_edit_date": 1587150658
```

I cannot figure out the data type of this dates and needs to convert them in to a standard date type to read easily and use in a graph. If any one can help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

All dates in the Stack Exchange API are in UNIX epoch time, which is the number of seconds since midnight UTC January 1st, 1970.

You can use `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.fromtimestamp(1587151634).strftime('%c')
```

Output:

```
Sat Apr 18 00:57:14 2020
```

I guess from here you can modify the output to make it easily readable.

Comment: I think it has to be `utcfromtimestamp()` or `fromtimestamp(..., tz=timezone.utc)`, otherwise, Python assumes you want the time converted to the platform you run this code on (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)).